# Remove clearfix from section class in custom theme

Tags: theming, blocks

I'm attempting to edit the template for my pages to allow it to show the content with a block beside it rather than beneath it. I'm currently using bootstrap to lay out my grid.

In my page.tpl.php I have

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <?php print render($page['sideblock']); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the content block and the sideblock to be side by side. However when the page renders it wraps the content block in

```
<section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">
```

I noticed that when I removed the clearfix class to the section tag I was able to display it side by side. But I don't see any method to remove the clearfix class from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easily be solved with jQuery, but I too would prefer to simply stop it from rendering.

Jquery:
$('#block-system-main').removeClass('clearfix');

Rendering:
Of course, you could rename the modules/system/region.tpl.php file to 'region--content.tpl.php' and put it in your sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME folder, then remove the "$classes" variable.

Comment: That worked great! I've actually been searching for a way to remove the classes from other regions as well, this helps immensely.

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 8, the best approach for this is to just copy the **bootstrap/block/block.html.twig** template from the bootstrap theme into your custom themes folder, and just remove the **'clearfix'** class from the twig classes block.

[image: block.html.twig template]

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without a link to the specific page. But try this, a CSS only solution:

```
#block-system-main.clearfix:after {
    display: inline;
    clear: none;
}
```